# R Shiny: Error Navbarpage Argument is missing with no default, shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I'm fairly new to shiny R and I'm so troubled by its format. I don't know how to organize it cleaner. I feel like I've checked everything, however I don't know what I'm missing. It keeps giving me ErrorNavbarPage argument is missing with no default! Where is my code wrong? Thank you

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage(title = "Demo Bar",
             tabPanel("Percent college",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          selectInput(inputId = "state", label = "Select a state:",
                                      choices = unique(midwest$state),
                                      selected = "IL",
                                      multiple = TRUE),
                          hr(),
                          helpText("Data From Midwest data frame"),
                          textInput(inputId = "title", label = "Write a title!", value = "Midwest scatter plot comparison")
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          plotlyOutput(outputId = "scatterplot")
                        ),
                      ),
             ),
             tabPanel("Data Page",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          sliderInput(
                            inputId = "area_choice",
                            label = "Range of Area",
                            min = area_range[1],
                            max = area_range[2],
                            value = area_range
                          ),
                        ),
                          mainPanel(
                            plotOutput("plot")
                          ),
                      ),
             ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: You have many extra commas.  You need to remove `","` whenever that is the last element.

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean sorryy . Could you point out where there might be extra commas?

Comment: Please remove all commas after  `mainPanel(  plotOutput("plot") )`, that is the last four commas in the `ui` are not necessary.

Comment: God bless you! Ur really helpful! Now I understand I had too many extra commas! hahaha these things are kinda all over the place!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working code without the extra commas:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage(
    title = "Demo Bar",
             tabPanel("Percent college",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          selectInput(inputId = "state", label = "Select a state:",
                                      choices = unique(midwest$state),
                                      selected = "IL",
                                      multiple = TRUE),
                          hr(),
                          helpText("Data From Midwest data frame"),
                          textInput(inputId = "title", label = "Write a title!", value = "Midwest scatter plot comparison")
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          plotOutput("plot1")
                          #plotlyOutput(outputId = "scatterplot")
                        ),
                      ),
             ),
             tabPanel("Data Page",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          sliderInput(
                            inputId = "area_choice",
                            label = "Range of Area",
                            min = 1, #area_range[1],
                            max = 10, #area_range[2],
                            value = 5 #area_range
                          )
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          plotOutput("plot2")
                        )
                      )
             )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot(plot(cars))
    output$plot2 <- renderPlot(plot(pressure))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you! U were a lot of help!